# Continue watching feature for stored video on aws with Elemental MediaPackage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, http-live-streaming, aws-mediapackage, aws-mediaservices

I am trying to build continue watching video on AWS. if the user left in between while watching video and come back again, he/she can continue watch from there. I am using aws MediaPackage to package and CloudFront as CDN to stream HLS video. Looking for some ways to store last .ts file accessed by the user and play back from same .ts file.

Answer (score 3):

MediaPackage accepts optional start-time and end-time parameters when generating a manifest (live event streams are constrained by the channel's configured start-over window). So, you could in theory store the current asset's name/URL and duration viewed in a player preference or cookie, then start a later session by requesting a manifest using that time offset as a starting point within the asset.  The segments themselves would come from CloudFront.